# How do you make xterm work on Cygwin to use IRAF?

Tags: cygwin, iraf

I need to use IRAF for astronomy labs, I’m attending remotely so I need to do it with my laptop. I installed Cygwin with the needed packages and IRAF but I don’t understand why when I try to open a terminal with xterm I just get a black window that crashes after a few seconds.

Comment: not a programming question, better move to SuperUser.  Look on documentation https://x.cygwin.com/docs/ug/cygwin-x-ug.html

Comment: IRAF uses its own special terminal emulator, "xgterm", which differs from xterm.

Comment: In the instructions that my lecturer provided to make it work, it says to use xterm because xgterm raises an error.

Comment: It would be nice if your lecturer would report the issue on https://github.com/iraf-community/x11iraf; however it should work. With Windows, the recommendation is to install the WoL (Windows on Linux) subsystem, and therein Ubuntu or Debian. This way you can easily install iraf, xgterm, ds9 and everything else you would need directly from the distribution.